# WPF ListView, как определить столбец при клике

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Имеется ListView в котором отображается список папок и файлов, к которому прикручено контекстное меню:

```xml
<ListView Name="listView" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" ItemsSource ="{Binding foldersInfo}">
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="contextMenu"  Opened="visibleContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Name="contextScan" Header="Сканировать" Click="proScan"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Name="openExplorer" Header="Открыть в проводнике" Click="explorer"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Name="openFile" Header="Открыть файл" Click="explorer" ></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Name="movFile" Header="Переместить файл" Click="remove" ></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="1"  Content="Содержимое папки " Click="sort" />
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" MaxWidth="16" MaxHeight="16" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="5,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn >
                <!--.... ещё 3 столбца-->
            </GridViewColumn>

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

В зависимости от того на каком элементе мы вызвали контекстное меню, оно какие то опции скрывает, какие то показывает

```cs
public void visibleContextMenu (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = listView.SelectedIndex;
    Folder folder = foldersInfo[index];
    string path = folder.path;
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        contextScan.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        openFile.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        contextScan.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        openFile.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Возникла необходимость показывать совсем другое контекстное меню, если оно вызывется на 4-м столбце.
Вопрос каким образом я могу определить, что вызов контекстного меню произошёл на определённом столбце?

Comment: Можно цеплять контекстное меню не к `ListView`, а к колонкам. В вашем случае можно попробовать прицепить отдельное  контекстное меню к 4 колонке. Оно переопределит глобальное. Не пишу это в ответ, потому что не уверен, сработает или нет. Я сам использую [паттерн **MVVM**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) + метод `CanExecute` класса `RelayCommand` для определения видимости пунктов контекстного меню, там немного по-другому это работает.

Comment: Интересная идея, но к ```GridViewColumn``` я не смог прикрутить ```ContextMenu```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример на базе **MVVM**.

Допустим, есть `ListView`, и у него есть общее контекстное меню, которое работает со списком выбранных элементов, а у элементов есть свои меню, которые просто показывают данные ячейки.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="listView" Margin="5" ItemsSource ="{Binding GridItems}">
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Общее меню" Command="{Binding CmdMain}" CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Первая колонка">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding First}">
                                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                        <ContextMenu>
                                            <MenuItem Header="Меню 1" Command="{Binding CmdFirst}"/>
                                        </ContextMenu>
                                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Вторая колонка">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Second}">
                                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                        <ContextMenu>
                                            <MenuItem Header="Меню 2" Command="{Binding CmdSecond}"/>
                                        </ContextMenu>
                                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Обратите внимание, я нигде не использовал имена для контролов. В MVVM это не нужно.

[image: WpfApp1]

Чтобы выполнять действия я буду использовать командный класс, взятый [отсюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern). Класс типовой, он или его аналог используется почти всеми авторами проектов на базе шаблона программирования **MVVM**.

Команды в **MVVM** - основной способ что-то выполнить, когда что-то нажато (для клавиш в xaml есть `KeyBinding`). Отличаются от событий тем, что в команду можно передать все что угодно, о чем знает UI с помощью тех же самых биндингов, а не только `sender` и `EventArgs`, собственно они здесь и не к чему. Еще плюс в обратной связи с помощью `CanExecute`, где вычисляется, можно ли в данный момент данную команду выполнить. То есть `MenuItem` делает что-то вроде этого:

```csharp
if (CanExecute(param)) Execute(param);
```

**RelayCommand.cs**

```csharp
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Дальше `MainViewModel` для окна, в ней будет заполняться и лежать коллекция, с которой я буду работать в `ListView`, а так же команда, которая на входе получает список выделенных элементов `ListView`.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataItem> _gridItems;
    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> GridItems
    {
        get => _gridItems;
        set
        {
            _gridItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GridItems));
        }
    }
    public ICommand CmdMain => new RelayCommand(obj =>
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        foreach (DataItem item in ((IList)obj).Cast<DataItem>()) 
        { 
            result += item.ToString() + "\r\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }, obj => true); // это CanExecute, если вернуть false, пункт контекстного меню,
                     // привязанный к этой команде, будет задизейблен
                     // obj - это то, что передано в CommandParameter в xaml
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        GridItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
        GridItems.Add(new DataItem() { First = "один", Second = "два" });
        GridItems.Add(new DataItem() { First = "три", Second = "четыре" });
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

И данные, представляющие строку для `ListView`, здесь же я положу пару команд для колоночных контекстных меню.

**DataItem.cs**

```csharp
public class DataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _first;
    private string _second;

    public string First
    {
        get => _first;
        set
        {
            _first = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(First));
        }
    }

    public string Second
    {
        get => _second;
        set
        {
            _second = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Second));
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return First + " " + Second;
    }

    public ICommand CmdSecond => new RelayCommand(obj =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Second);
    }, obj => true);

    public ICommand CmdFirst => new RelayCommand(obj =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(First);
    }, obj => true);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Реализация интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged` позволяет UI элементам узнавать об изменениях в данных самостоятельно с помощью биндингов. Как результат, програмная логика в **MVVM**, вообще не обращается к контролам, она может даже не знать об их существовании. Грубо говоря, можно один и тот же класс с данными использовать как `DataContext` для нескольких контролов в совершенно разных, не похожих друг на друга интерфейсах (и этим многие пользуются).

И напоследок, самая интересная часть большинства проектов на базе **MVVM**:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```csharp
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Безусловно ответ полностью отвечает на мой вопрос, но ещё больше ответ пытается рекламировать MVVM :) Ничего против не имею, но я пишу в основном для себя и для друзей, потому мои проекты не очень большие и когда я для себя решил познать MVVM то увы никаких глобальных преимуществ не нашёл :( Да я написал всего 2 проекта на MVVM и кое что безусловно понравилось, но решая банальные задачи мне пришлось пробираться через дебри, что бы всё организовать через MVVM. В итоге я со всеми своими задачами справился, но для себя решил: пока не осознаю истинную мощь MVVM буду кодить в code-behind