# Как передать элемент ListView в CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть ListView и на каждом ListViewItem есть кнопка, как мне передать в CommandParameter элемент на котором находится нажатая кнопка? Или как определить на каком именно элементе из списка ListView была нажата кнопка?

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot Да, спасибо. Я по незнанию указывал DataContex для всей кнопки, в итоге возвращала она всю ViewModel. По этому думал что проблема в CommandParameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас команда в элементе списка, то вы и вызываете эту команду из элемента списка, то есть для кода в команде это `this`. Какой смысл в параметре вообще?

Если это команда где-то в другом месте, например в главной вью-модели,  а кнопка в элементе списка, то как-то так:

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Похожие вопросы были:

- [Как сделать биндинг кнопки которая внутри элемента ListView WPF MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1115981/373567)
- [WPF ListView, как определить столбец при клике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1090500/373567)