# Как удалить строку listview?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть база данных sql со списком пользователей. Все выводится в listview. Так же, в каждой строке присутствует кнопка "удалить" и "редактировать": [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю как найти индекс строки, чтобы в будущем, используя его, удалить/редактировать строку. Если надо, то от код вставки данных:

```
string ConnectionString = $"select * from Manager";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(ConnectionString, dataBase.GetConnection());

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);

        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) 
        {
            manager dataUser = new manager()     
            {
                Name = table.Rows[i][1].ToString(),    
                SurName = table.Rows[i][2].ToString(),        
                Patronimic = table.Rows[i][3].ToString(),  
                UserName = table.Rows[i][4].ToString(),    
                Password = table.Rows[i][5].ToString(),      
                Email = table.Rows[i][6].ToString(),  
                Address = table.Rows[i][7].ToString(),         
                PhoneNumber = table.Rows[i][8].ToString(),
            };
            ListManager.Items.Add(dataUser); 
        }
```

Вот xaml:

```
            <ListView x:Name="ListManager" Grid.Row="3" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Имя" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Фамилия" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SurName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Отчество" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Patronimic}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Логин" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Пароль" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Password}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Адрес" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Телефон" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PhoneNumber}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Delete" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Width="60" Content="Delete" Click="btnDelete_Click"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Width="60" Margin="10,0,0,0" Content="Edit" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Используйте команды и привязки, решите тогда эту задачу в несколько строк кода. Сейчас ваша проблема в том, что у вас каша, перемешены данные и UI, из-за чего вы и попали в этот тупик. А так, если хотите костыль, то сделайте `<Button Tag="{Binding}"`, а в обработчике кнопки делайте нечто на подобии `if (sender is Button btn && btn.Tag is manager manager){ ... }` где `manager` будет ваш класс с данными, с которым уже делайте что надо. Но повторю, это костыль, как и то, что вы делаете сейчас, поймите привязки, отделите данные от UI.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1462492/373567 там еще прилинкованы 2 ответа, должно хватить информации